# What happens if a ThreadPool thread dies?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

What would happen if a thread for some reason dies or if I manually call "Abort" on a ThreadPool thread?
Will .NET recreate a new one to fill its slot or will the threadpool simply run out of threads eventually?

And maybe this is a separate question, but does the threadpool deal with zombie processes?
if I queue a task with a while(true) loop in it to the threadpool, will it spin forever or will the threadpool kill this thread eventually?

So the real question might be; what happens if a job never finishes in the .NET threadpool.
Is that taken care of somehow?

Comment: why would you ever use `Thread.Abort()` ? Just *exit the thread-pool method cleanly*...

Comment: I know that, I just wonder what would actually happen in reality

Comment: It gets buried beneath a pile of roses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET thread pool uses a [hill-climbing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx) algorithm to estimate the optimal number of worker threads that should be active at any point in time. If you kill such a worker thread, a new one will be recreated on the next check.

As to your second question: A non-terminating task will be allowed to run indefinitely. However, worker threads are considered [background threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); so once all your foreground threads have exited, your process will exit as well (killing the background threads).